# Is there rich card support for Cisco spark (now Webex teams) Bot

Tags: bots, cisco, botkit, webex

I am implementing a cisco spark bot , which is now known as Webex teams. I am able to send receive simple text message from user. Is there a way to send rich card to user from Bot? I could not find any helpful documentation.

Here is my code I use to interact with bot

```
var SparkBot = require("node-sparkbot");

var SparkAPIWrapper = require("node-sparkclient");
// Starts your Webhook with default configuration where the SPARK API access 
token is read from the SPARK_TOKEN env variable 
var bot = new SparkBot();

var spark = new SparkAPIWrapper(process.env.SPARK_TOKEN);

bot.onMessage(function (trigger, message) {
     if (message.personEmail != "mytestbot@webex.bot")

       spark.createMessage(message.roomId, "You said " + message.text, { 
       "markdown": 
        true }, function (err, message) {
        if (err) {
        console.log("WARNING: could not post message to room: " + 
        message.roomId);
        return;
       }
    });
});
```

Rich cards may contain buttons , links, list , thumbnail etc..

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet on the platform side. The best you have at the moment is you can use markdown to style messages.

Comment: You can, here is a list of message formatting options:
https://developer.webex.com/formatting-messages.html

Webex Teams runs a public channel if you need help getting started:
https://eurl.io/#SyNZuomKx

Comment: the link refers to message formatting via REst API. I am looking for node js library methods.

Comment: The API is the limiting factor, you have to use what formatting objects they provide.